# Async/Await no longer works within my dispatched function

Tags: reactjs, async-await, react-hooks

I have a simple fetch request to get some blog posts.

```
const getBlogPosts = dispatch => {
  return async () => {
    console.log('is this being reached?')
    // const response = await jsonServer.get('/blogposts');
    const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')

    console.log('show me the response: ', await response.json());

    dispatch({ type: 'get_blogposts', payload: response.data });
  };
};
```

My reducer:

```
const blogReducer = (state, action) => {
  // console.log('show me the state inside the reducer: ', action);
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'add_blogpost':
      return [
        ...state,
        {
          id: Math.floor(Math.random() * 999),
          title: action.payload.title,
          content: action.payload.content,
        },
      ];
    case 'get_blogposts':
      console.log('show me action.payload: ', action);
      return action.payload;
    case 'delete_blogpost':
      return state.filter(blogPost => blogPost.id !== action.payload);
    // case 'check_blog':
    //   console.log('wtf??')
    //   return state;
    case 'edit_blogpost':
      return state.map(blogPost => {
        return blogPost.id === action.payload.id ? action.payload : blogPost;
      });
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I export the Context and Provider via:

```
export const {Context, Provider} = createDataContext(
  blogReducer,
  {addBlogPost, deleteBlogPost, editBlogPost, getBlogPosts},
  [],
);
```

My createDataContext:

```
import React, {useReducer, useEffect} from 'react';

export default (reducer, actions, initialState) => {
  const Context = React.createContext();
  const Provider = ({children}) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, initialState);
    // actions === { addBlogPost: (dispatch) => {return () => }}

    const boundActions = {};

    for (let key in actions) {
      boundActions[key] = actions[key](dispatch);
    }
    return (
      <Context.Provider value={{state, ...boundActions}}>
        {children}
      </Context.Provider>
    );
  };
  return {Context, Provider};
};
```

If I use POSTMAN to make a request to `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1`, it comes back fine.  However, when I try to do the same thing using async/await + fetch.  The request gets hung up and never completes.  I've also tried using axios and encountered the same issue.

Here is the plain js that I tried and got to work properly.

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

const getBlogPosts = async () => {
    // const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    const response = await fetch('http://5aa599ff.ngrok.io/blogposts');
    const final = await response.json();
    console.log('show me something nice: ', final)

}
getBlogPosts();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here `response.data` is undefined since your response object doesn't contain `data` key. instead use `response.json()` which also need await so do something like this:

```
    const response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')

    console.log('show me the response: ', await response.json());
```

here is a working example with your endpoint https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-li1pb

Comment: I got your code to work when I tried it in a plain js file.  However, when I went back to my app and tried it, I'm still not seeing the second console log.  I'm only seeing "is this being reached", but I'm not seeing "show me the response"

Comment: can you add your code to sandbox that way it is easy to help you out and where are you calling the getBlogPosts function ?

Comment: I've added it, but I forgot to add that this is a react native project.  I've added BlogContext.js and createDataContext.js

Comment: Nevermind, I rebooted my system and everything worked!